# Average Lng/Lat NaN Issues

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, average

I'm an amateur programmer and working on a project I have in mind using the google maps API. Long story short, I'm trying to create a variable with the average longitude and latitude of n number of points.  I'm to the point that I have an array of the lng/lat coordinates, but I'm struggling to convert them into a format that I can use as input for a google maps LatLng method.

I've referenced this SO question, [Find the average (center) of lats/lngs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235430/find-the-average-center-of-lats-lngs), and numerous other websites for a month now, but I haven't been able to understand or implement a solution. I feel like I'm missing the simple stuff, but I've been banging my head against this for a month, and not getting anywhere.  Any advice or help with this would be appreciated.

```
 //GOOGLE MAPS API SCRIPTS
var streetarray = document.getElementsByName("street");
var cityarray = document.getElementsByName("city");
var geocoder;
var map;
var results;
var mapArray = new Array();
var avgLat;
var avgLng;


function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    //centered on Carrollton, Texas -- Change lat,long values to change initial map area
    center:
     new google.maps.LatLng(32.999173, -96.897413)
  }
  //change Id reference to the div/container that contains the google map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  //Loop through and concate street and city values to find long,lat values for all fields
  for (var cName = 0; cName < namearray.length; cName++){
  var address = streetarray[cName].value + cityarray[cName].value;

  //start geocode copy  & paste text from API reference
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var results = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(results);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results,

      });
    //Push lng/lat locations to the mapArray
    mapArray.push(results);
    //Loop through mapArray to add Lat/Lng values, and then divide by j (number of locations) to find the average
    for (var i in mapArray) {
    var avgLat = 0;
    var avgLng = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var avgLat = (avgLat + mapArray[i][1]);
    var avgLng = (avgLng + mapArray[i][2]);
    console.log(mapArray, avgLat, avgLng);
    j++;
}

avgLat = avgLat / j;
avgLng = avgLng / j;


    var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: results,
      radius: 15000,
      strokeColor:"#0000FF",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,
      strokeWeight:2,
      fillColor:"#0000FF",
      fillOpacity:0.4


    })
      markerCircle.setMap(map);


    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

- `results[0].geometry.location` is not an array, it's an object(a `google.maps.LatLng`). Use the methods `lat()` and `lng()` to retrieve latitude and longitude
- `var avgLat = 0;`
     `var avgLng = 0;`
      `var j = 0;`.

  You must move this to outside of the loop, otherwise the variables will be cleared on each loop.

Comment: That's makes sense! I didn't catch the the problem with the loop at all..... thank you!

One question about the results...comment.  I created a new array called mapArray and pushed the values of results[0].geometry.location to that array so I could loop through them and pull the lat() lng() that way; is that the best way to do it, or would it be better to work directly with the results object?

Comment: You cant work directly without any helper, because the responses arrive one by one. What you can do instead of the additional loop is to store 3 global variables for the number of markers, the sum of latitude and the sum of longitude. Update these variables each time you get a response and calculate the average based on these variables, then you don't need to loop through the increasing  array each time.